# ScanningActivity has leaked IntentReceiver and then a NullPointException

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

Im working on implemention of my app that print a receipt.
I use the library Printooth for this implementetion but i met 2 issue that dont le me continue.
I have the button as show below, when i click it first search and let you pair with a bluetooth device and then when is paired and click again, print some text.
The issues are 2, in order of sequence there are:

1. `E/ActivityThread: Activity com.mazenrashed.printooth.ui.ScanningActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.mazenrashed.printooth.utilities.Bluetooth$3@dd8369f that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
   android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.mazenrashed.printooth.ui.ScanningActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.mazenrashed.printooth.utilities.Bluetooth$3@dd8369f that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
2. --------- beginning of crash
   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.testaapplication0209, PID: 3667
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.mazenrashed.printooth.utilities.Printing.print(java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference

Here the full code:

```
package com.example.testaapplication0209;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mazenrashed.printooth.Printooth;
import com.mazenrashed.printooth.data.printable.Printable;
import com.mazenrashed.printooth.data.printable.RawPrintable;
import com.mazenrashed.printooth.data.printable.TextPrintable;
import com.mazenrashed.printooth.data.printer.DefaultPrinter;
import com.mazenrashed.printooth.ui.ScanningActivity;
import com.mazenrashed.printooth.utilities.Printing;
import com.mazenrashed.printooth.utilities.PrintingCallback;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class PrintActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Printing printing = null;
private PrintingCallback printingCallback = null;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_print);

    if (Printooth.INSTANCE.hasPairedPrinter())
        printing = Printooth.INSTANCE.printer();
    initViews();
    initListeners();

    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!Printooth.INSTANCE.hasPairedPrinter())
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(PrintActivity.this, ScanningActivity.class), ScanningActivity.SCANNING_FOR_PRINTER);
            else
                printText();
        }
    });
}

private void initListeners() {
    if (printing!=null && printingCallback==null) {
        Log.d("xxx", "initListeners ");
        printingCallback = new PrintingCallback() {

            public void connectingWithPrinter() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connecting with printer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("xxx", "Connecting");
            }
            public void printingOrderSentSuccessfully() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "printingOrderSentSuccessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("xxx", "printingOrderSentSuccessfully");

            }
            public void connectionFailed(@NonNull String error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "connectionFailed :"+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("xxx", "connectionFailed : "+error);
            }
            public void onError(@NonNull String error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onError :"+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("xxx", "onError : "+error);
            }
            public void onMessage(@NonNull String message) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onMessage :" +message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("xxx", "onMessage : "+message);
            }
        };

        Printooth.INSTANCE.printer().setPrintingCallback(printingCallback);
    }
}
private void initViews() {
    if (Printooth.INSTANCE.getPairedPrinter()!=null)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (Printooth.INSTANCE.hasPairedPrinter())?("Un-pair "+ Printooth.INSTANCE.getPairedPrinter().getName()):"Pair with printer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void printText() {
    ArrayList<Printable> printables = new ArrayList<>();
    printables.add(new RawPrintable.Builder(new byte[]{27, 100, 4}).build());

    //Add Text
    printables.add(new TextPrintable.Builder()
            .setText("Hello World: Jagadeesh")
            .setCharacterCode(DefaultPrinter.Companion.getCHARCODE_PC1252())
            .setNewLinesAfter(1)
            .build());

    printables.add((new TextPrintable.Builder())
            .setText(" Hello World : été è à '€' içi Bò Xào Coi Xanh")
            .setCharacterCode(DefaultPrinter.Companion.getCHARCODE_PC1252())
            .setNewLinesAfter(1)
            .build());

    //Custom Text
    printables.add((new TextPrintable.Builder())
            .setText("Hello World")
            .setLineSpacing(DefaultPrinter.Companion.getLINE_SPACING_60())
            .setAlignment(DefaultPrinter.Companion.getALIGNMENT_CENTER())
            .setEmphasizedMode(DefaultPrinter.Companion.getEMPHASIZED_MODE_BOLD())
            .setUnderlined(DefaultPrinter.Companion.getUNDERLINED_MODE_ON())
            .setNewLinesAfter(1)
            .build());

    printing.print(printables);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("xxx", "onActivityResult "+requestCode);

    if (requestCode == ScanningActivity.SCANNING_FOR_PRINTER && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        initListeners();
    }
    initViews();
}
```

}

I have also have an application class and all permiss in manifest.xml

Can anyone now how to solve this?

`